# Problem with SQL subquery: Unrecognized name for Primary Key

Tags: sql, subquery

—SQL question: I am trying to JOIN the customer_purchases table with the customer_address table. I also included a subquery so that I can count the how many products a customer (id) bought. Unfortunately, the query is not able to run due to
Unrecognized name: `Customer_data.customer_purchases.customer_id` at [14:4]
Will appreciate if someone can give me an idea of what I did wrong. Thank you!

```
   SELECT 
    customer_purchases.customer_id,
    customer_details.name AS customer_name,
    num_products_bought.product AS num_bought,
   FROM
     (SELECT
     customer_id,
     COUNT(*)product,
     FROM `my-project3648.Customer_data.customer_purchases` AS customer_purchases
     GROUP BY customer_id 
     ) AS num_products_bought

   INNER JOIN `my-project3648.Customer_data.customer_address` AS customer_details 
   *ON customer_purchases.customer_id* = customer_details.customer_id
   GROUP BY
   customer_id, customer_name, product;
```

Problem emerged when i changed position of my FROM to line 5 (before subquery) from previous position of after subquery. Before that, the query was not able to recognise subquery ALIAS of num_products_bought.

Comment: You have a multiple trailing commas before  both `from` and unusually named objects. `\` \`` delimits the name of an object you don't need this.

Answer (score 2):

You are referring the table customer_purchases but its part of a subquery which output is num_products_bought. so use num_products_bought instead of customer_purchases
try this below:

```
       SELECT 
    num_products_bought.customer_id,
    customer_details.name AS customer_name,
    num_products_bought.product AS num_bought,
   FROM
     (SELECT
     customer_id,
     COUNT(*)product,
     FROM 'my-project3648.Customer_data.customer_purchases' AS customer_purchases
     GROUP BY customer_id 
     ) AS num_products_bought

   INNER JOIN `my-project3648.Customer_data.customer_address` AS customer_details 
   ON num_products_bought.customer_id = customer_details.customer_id
   GROUP BY
   customer_id, customer_name, product;
```

Hope this helps